# How to reduce lag in Turtlebot3 Camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ros

I am using turtlebot3 waffle_pi with default camera and raspberry pi4 4GB.

Have an issue with lag,
why does this camera cant operate smoothly with higher fps?
this camera uses 640 * 480 resolution (default setting in turtlebot3_bringup)

I am using this code to stream my camera

this code runs on

- ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic

````
import rospy
import cv2


from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CompressedImage
from cv_bridge import CvBridge

bridge = CvBridge()

def image_cb(data):
    cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    cv2.imshow('raw image', cv_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('turtlebot3_rl_camera')
    rospy.Subscriber("/camera/image", Image, image_cb)
    rospy.spin()```
````

Comment: you might want to use the `CompressedImage` that you are importing instead of the `Image` itself, as the compression reduces the size, and hence the lag.

Comment: cv_bridge doesn't support `CompressedImage`, if it ur answer so I must change the whole program

Comment: You might want to look into <http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport>. Ideally you would want to make image publisher and subscriber as nodelets in same nodelet manager so that there would be no overhead for (un)serializing data <http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet>. But it's only available in C++ so maybe not an option